# I have phone number which I want to show the number first three number and last two number like 700XXXXX20 like this?

Tags: flutter

I have phone number which I want to show the number first three number and last two number like 700XXXXX20 like this. How can I show that? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried something yourself in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var i =0;
  var buffer = new StringBuffer();
<your number string>.runes.forEach((int rune) {
  ++i;
  var character=new String.fromCharCode(rune);
  if(i >2 && i<9){
    buffer.write("*");
  }else{
    buffer.write(character);   
  }
});
  print(buffer);
```

You can use **buffer** for your state change to update UI

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't substring work for you?

Something like

```
String hiddenPhone = '${phone.substring(0,3)}${'X' * (phone.length - 5)}${phone.substring(phone.length - 2)}';
```